# MySQL friend relation

Tags: sql

I have three tables (architect, designer, connections). Architect can connect(like friend requests in FB) to designers

**Schema of the tables**

architect Table -> userId,username ,email,password,location,contact

designer Table -> userId,username,email,password,location,job

connection Table -> userID(this is a foreign key that references userId in the architect table ) ,designersId(this is also a foreign key that references userId in the designer table).

**NOTE**: A architect can have many connections. A same designer can be connected to multiple architects (Just works like friends on FB)

[image: Architect table]

[image: designer table]

[image]

I want to get a list of all connections for a specific architect

**I did it like this**

```
SELECT designer.username,
       designer.location,
       designer.contact,
       designer.job,
       designer.rating,    
       connections.designersId 
FROM designer 
INNER JOIN connections ON designer.userId = connections.designersId 
                      AND connections.userId ="The user Id of the architect"
```

I am getting correct results by this method but is this the correct approach I don't really know and I just wanted to know if I made the schema's right and the SQL commands clean.

Thank you.

P.s I ignored the unwanted columns in table don't mind those

Comment: *is this the correct approach* Why not? the only point - in INNER JOIN the conditions by one of the tables only are placed to WHERE clause in general.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. I have removed all but the tag [[tag:sql]]. Just tag the things related to what you are asking about; tehre's no way you are using all 3 of those RDBMS simultaneously.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Your query is fine and probably the most efficient way to write the logic in almost all databases.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but as you merely want to select designers, I would not join, but select from designers table only and put my criteria in the where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM designer 
WHERE userId IN (SELECT designersid FROM connections WHERE architectid = 123);
```

(I've renamed the connections.userid to architectid in my query, so as to get this more readable. If you want to stick with the column name userid, change this in the query, but I suggest you rather rename the column in the table to make it clear what that userid means. I'd even rename the columns userid in the designer and architect tables to designerid and architectid unless there really is an additional user table.)